# Apple Push Notification at parse.com

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have got the push notification through parse.com but I need to get from local server. Is it possible to enable our local url at parse.com to get notification to various devices?

Answer (score 0):

As we aware about parse it provide the interface to `APNS` and when we integrate it with our iOS project we need to add the given framework so that the device token captured on `parse.com` user account.

As per your requirement not possible but you can developer your own server for sending push notification that will communicate with `APNS` using your `.p12` file and capture your device token.

For Best Practice you can work and test your app with parse.com and then same implement with your own server like create the SSL certificate and [all follow here](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) ..then try it on parse.com if everything work fine then start work on your own server and research.

For Java You Can use 
[java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) as it is a Java client for Apple Push Notification service (APNs). The library aims to provide a highly scalable interface to the Apple server, while still being simple and modular.

[Steps for include .](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)

**UPDATE**

```
String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("Can't be simpler than this!").build();
String token = "fedfbcfb....";
service.push(token, payload);
```

`payload` is your text message that you want to deliver and `token` is your `iOS` device token
that you will get when you enable you `iOS App ID` for push notification.

Comment: do u have any tutorial or example to follow the steps. please tell me sir i am new to ios

Comment: first select you platform as i used java and as in given link follow the steps will help you sure

Comment: how to include this to my ios project sir

Comment: first test your app with parse.com if everything work fine like push notifications working then implement your own server with same configurations.

Comment: String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("Can't be simpler than this!").build();
String token = "fedfbcfb....";
service.push(token, payload); where i want to give these code sir

Comment: ya its working fine with parse.com i need local url sir

Comment: your case you using parse if you need local url for register device token your need to implement your own server

Comment: Sir for that only how to create my own server